# Cómo corregir este error al ingresar los datos desde un winforms conectado a sql?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, sql-server-2017, conexión

```
create table Clientes
(
IDCliente int primary key identity (1,1) not null,
NombreCliente varchar (100) not null,
PrimerApellidoCliente varchar (100) not null,
SegundoApellidoCliente varchar (100) not null,
DireccionCliente varchar (100) not null,
TelefonoCliente int not null,


);
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Clientes' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.'

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que estás usando? El error es claro, pero no te podemos ayudar sin ver que estás haciendo.

Comment: Pues eso. Estás intentando insertar una fila incluyendo el valor del campo idcliente pero esa columna es identity y se va a generar solita. Sin ver cómo intentas insertar, es todo lo que podemos opinar/ Si quieres, puedes [edit] la pregunta todo lo que quieras y añades más info y más código.

Answer (score 2):

Como la llave primaria es identity (1,1), se va generar automaticamente , tuve que eliminar de la variable consulta el .Text de la misma llave primaria . ya que lo iba a generar automaticamente .
Gracias a Todos

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 0):

Si el campo ha sido configurado como Identity no nulo simplemente no puedes insertar el IDCliente SQL se encargara de hacerlo por ti, ahora si ver lo que haces es dificil ayudar, mi primer comentario se basa solo en la info que suministras